# Issue Badges for closed/opened to display on GitHub Markdown files

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I have a [markdown page on GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/TRANSLATING.md/#incremental) where I am referencing a number of issues.
It would be really handy if there was a way to include an image/icon that would display the issue status (closed or opened) from within that Markdown file, just like people do with the Travis "Build passing" badge.

I am envisioning something like:

[image: Issue badges]

Is there any way to do such a thing?  And maybe even display labels, in addition to the status (open/closed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't fully supported yet:

- this was requested in [github/markup issue 965](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/965)
- this was implemented (for total of issues only) in [badges/shields PR 1020](https://github.com/badges/shields/pull/1020)

Maybe the [badges/shields](https://github.com/badges/shields) will implement a badge for a given issue.